# Temporary Subscription using Jabber-net client

Tags: c#, .net, xmpp

I am using Jabber-net for one of my application. Currently we are using Permanent Subscribtions. For some reason we have some problem with Permanent subscriptions. Now, we want to use Temporary Subscription. My questions is simple: 
Is that Jabber-net supports Temporary Subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(speaking as the Jabber-Net author)

No.

Comment: Thanx Joe. Is that it is documented or written anywhere? Actually I want to confirm this. And if jabber-net does not support Temporary subscription than who else supports Temporary subscripton?

Comment: As far as I know, temporary subscriptions have not been standardized, so it is likely that nobody implements it.  Ask your sever vendor for details.